# c++ : How to bind inherited methods only to parent classes?

Tags: c++, inheritance

i've stumbled upon this problem while doing multi-base inheritance project for my college work. Example of my problem, and code itself:
 I'm setting up 3 classes, A, B and C. 
B inherits publicly from A. 
C inherits publicly from B.
I want to set a method publicly in B, that does take as argument a pointer to an object of class A. However it should be able to use only class A objects, neither B or C. 
Problem is that Visual Studio 2013 doesn't show any error, and simply allows for my method to be used by B class object on a C class object, which is exactly the opposite of what i want to achieve. 
 
Why is that happening?
Does that mean that inheriting somewhat makes C object being interpreted as of type A, B and C at the same time? If not, is there a direct way to bind a method to be used only on classes that it inherits from (c methods on both A and B objects)? Feel free to correct me if i'm wrong anywhere, i'm still a newbie at programing. Thank you for your help! 
    `

```
class A
{
private: 
    int x;
    string z;
public:
    void SetZ()
    {
        cout << "Set Z: ";
        cin >> z;
    }
    string GetZ()
    {
        return this->z;
    }
};

class B
    :public A
{
public:
    void use_base(A* k)
    {
        cout << "here and now, i'm using " << k->GetZ() << " however i, " << this->GetZ() << ", might want to!";
    }
};

class C
    :public B
{
    void use_base(A* k)
    {
        cout << "extra";
    }
};

int main()
{
    A Bob;
    B Mark;
    Bob.SetZ();
    Mark.SetZ();
    C Karl;
    Mark.use_base(&Karl); // doesn't show any error

    return 0;
}`
```

Comment: "Does that mean that inheriting somewhat makes C object being interpreted as of type A..."  public inheritance models a is-a relation thus yes, `class C : public B` means: any `C` is a `B` (and as any `B` is an `A` also any `C` is allowed when an `A` is required).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `B` inherits publicly from `A`, then `B*` can be implicitly converted to `A*` so a function that takes `A*` can be called with `B*` arguments. To prevent this, you could make the inheritance protected or private. However, that might create other problems.

To prevent accidentally passing a `B*`, you can declare another overload that takes `B*` and delete it. This overload will win for `B*` and `C*` arguments and cause a compilation error. You can also generalize this approach using templates, and so prevent passing a pointer to any class derived from `A`, without naming all such classes.

```
void use_base(A* k) { /* do something */ }
void use_base(B*) = delete;
```

However, that doesn't stop someone from explicitly casting a `B*` or `C*` to `A*` and calling the `A*` overload.